# I am trying to implement a UISplitViewController on IPhone similar to the Discover App

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to implement UISplitViewController on iPhone similar to the Discover App. The Primary View controller has to semi-overlay on top of the detail View Controller. I have tried the existing frameworks but in all of them the master/primary view controller pushes the detail view controller when the menuItem/Hamburger button on detailView is pressed. Any ideas or resources related to my specific requirement ? 
[I am trying to implement something similar to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCvRo.jpg)

When you click on a certain item in the master , the corresponding view is pushed to the detailView and the master closes

Comment: What is the Discover App? Can you share some screenshots and code what you already have tried?

Comment: I have added the image of the view that I am trying to achieve

Comment: Please fix the link, it should read like this: `![I am trying to implement something similar to the picture][1]`

Comment: I cannot post an image . It seems like I need to have a reputation of 10 to post an image.